# Is 1 hour 10 minutes sufficient to transit in Dubai airport arriving from Johannesburg and departing to Standsted UK?

Tags: transit, dubai, emirates

Arrival time at Dubai on EK766 on 7/5/2019 is 08.20 and departure to London Standsted EK33 is at 09.30 on the same day. I am 73 years old and I would think that I would need assistance? Can this be arranged and if so how?

Comment: This is on one ticket, right? Call the airline and ask for assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If it's all on one-ticket then Emirates will take care of it, it's their problem/issue. Also note emirates pad their connection times anyway, but if the connection becomes tight they will send a rep to the gate to meet passengers for tight connections. If it becomes really tight (due to late departure of first flight) ask a cabin member to ask ground services to send a golf cart so you aren't being made to run with the rep.  Many Emirates flight pairs have tight connection sometimes as little as 45 minutes and it all works out.